# OnParticleCollision doesn't get triggered in Unity 2018.2

Tags: unity-game-engine

After loading my Unity 2018.1.1 project in Untiy 2018.2.2, the OnParticleCollision method doesn't get triggered at all. Everything worked fine in Unity 2018.1.1.

There's no official information about updating particle collisions whatsoever.

Here's my C# code for the Enemy script.

The Player GameObject has a particle system that serves as a weapon + the Collision module is enabled and is properly set up to collide with the Enemies layer.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Enemy health
    private int health = 100;

    // !!! Doesn't get triggered at all !!!
    // When the player's weapon hits the Enemy
    private void OnParticleCollision(GameObject other)
    {
        Debug.Log(other.tag);

        if (other.tag == "Weapon")
        {
            // Reduce health
            health -= 50;
            if (health <= 0)
            {
                // Disable the Enemy that was just killed
                gameObject.SetActive(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Select the particle system, make sure that the Collison module is enabled. Now make sure that its *"Send Collision Messages"* is also enabled.

Comment: Yes, it is enabled. As I mentioned above, everything worked flawlessly in Unity 2018.1.1

Comment: Check if gameobjects still have 'Weapon' tag. Sometimes it happens that between version upgrades, the gameobjects tags are lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it.

The "Is Trigger" was checked in the Collider component on my Enemy prefab. For some reason, it works either way in 2018.1 and only works with "Is Trigger" unchecked in 2018.2.

Just in case you have the same problem, just uncheck the "Is Trigger" on your GameObjects and everything should work just fine.